# How do I make a color grid with hover pop up?

Tags: html, web, colors

I want to make something like this to display different types of wall paints. I need to be able to use it as an iframe.

It should display colors in a grid and when hovering on each box, it should show the color name and code. (attached below)

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6m4G.png)

Comment: Please insert your code that you have created so far... So we can help mire specific!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav you can improve it

```
#box-one{
   background: url('**') 50px 50px;
}
#box-one a:hover {
  /*pop up css*/
}
```